# In Django i want to display folders like google drive

Tags: python, html, django, django-queryset

This is my models.py. Displaying in folder structure format.

```
class Folder(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='userfolders')
    folder = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='folders', null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(_('Folder Name'), max_length=70)

class File(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='userfiles')
    folder = models.ForeignKey(Folder, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='folderfiles')
    description = models.CharField(_('File Description'), max_length=70)
    location = models.FileField(_('Location of the File'), upload_to=file_location_path, null=True, blank=True)
```

In the model as you can see i have folder with a self foreign key and file can be associated to a folder.

```
Folder------+---Old Folder
            +---Folder1-+--Cats.jpg
            |           +--File1.jpg
            +---File1.txt
File
Folder New -+---Puppy.jpg
            +---Dogs----+--Dog1.jpg
                        +--Dog2.jpg
                        +--Dog3.jpg

| 1st level | 2nd level | 3rd level |
```

How can i display the 1st level first and then if the user selects a folder then it should show its content. for example, if Folder New is selected then the users should see file named Puppy.jpg and folder named Dogs. Is this possible?